# Karate-gatling execution error : com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message, http call failed

Tags: karate

Using existing karat automation script for performance testing. Same script working fine with karate execution but with gatling execution is failing with error in put call other call working fine -  ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message, http call failed.

[image]

Tried adding
karate.configure('ssl', { trustAll: true });
in karate-config and

- configure ssl = true
- configure ssl = { trustAll: true }
  in feature file

Comment: clearly you have missed some config. you will have to troubleshoot this yourself or follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas Can you advice is there is any additional configuration we need to follow specific to gatling? Same scripts work fine with just karate and fails with gatling. If you can also advice on how to get detailed karate report[header details], in gatling logs

Comment: everything you should need should be in the docs. I can't repeat the documentation here. pay attention to where your classpath root is so that your logging configuration is picked up. it can be `src/test/scala` or `src/test/java` or `src/test/resources`. you can help by letting us know how to improve the documentation if needed